# FCM Registration token not getting

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in iOS I am using firebase for iOS push notification and I am using objective c . According to firebase tutorial I am getting notifications properly back ground and foreground .Now I want registration tokens to make device groups for notifications.So am not getting registration token how can I do that, here is my code.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseMessaging;
@import FirebaseInstanceID;
//#import <FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h>

//@import FirebaseMessaging;
@import UserNotifications;

//@import FirebaseMessaging;
@interface AppDelegate ()<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate,FIRMessagingDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //setup configure
    [FIRApp configure];

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]

   // [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate=self;
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]

    if ([UNUserNotificationCenter class] != nil) {
        // iOS 10 or later
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
        UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             // ...
         }];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 notifications aren't available; fall back to iOS 8-9 notifications.
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];




    return YES;
}

// [START receive_message]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);


}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

    // Print message ID.
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
    NSLog(@"App is on foreground");
}

// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
        NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
    }

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

    completionHandler();
}

// [END ios_10_message_handling]

// [START refresh_token]
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken {
    NSLog(@"FCM registration token: %@", fcmToken);
    // Notify about received token.
    NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fcmToken forKey:@"token"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
     @"FCMToken" object:nil userInfo:dataDict];
    NSLog(@"All is done");
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set [Messaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel to YES.
- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
    NSLog(@"Received data message: %@", remoteMessage.appData);
}
// [END ios_10_data_message]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Get Device Tokens....
    NSLog(@"APNs device token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs device token here.
   //  [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncomment this line:

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].delegate=self;
```

FCM provides the token via FIRMessagingDelegate's `messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: method` and you need to assign a delegate to `FIRMessaging` in order for that method to be called.

Comment: Thankyou sir for your revert back and I have already gotten the solution . anyway Thankyou so much for your reply.